# Reading Google Voice SMS Msgs using PHP

Tags: php, google-voice

Is there anyway for me to read my SMS inbox in google voice using a PHP webserver call?

Comment: these link might be helpfull http://codecri.me/case/66/sending-a-google-voice-sms-using-php/ and https://github.com/aaronpk/Google-Voice-PHP-API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several wrappers for that,

in java: http://code.google.com/p/google-voice-java/ (also ported to c#: http://code.google.com/p/sharp-voice/), in python: http://code.google.com/p/pygooglevoice/

I suppose you could port one of those to PHP